# What does “big fight on its hands” mean? Especially the phrase “on its hands”?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I think the Crimean government may have a big fight **on its hands** persuading citizens to endorse joining Russia.
> <sub>Source: [BBC News - Ukraine crisis: Crimea vote 'will not be recognised'](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-26483818)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> ## **on someone's hands**
>
> 1. Used to indicate that someone is responsible for dealing with someone or something:
>      
>    *he has a difficult job **on his hands***
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries definition of “on someone's hands”](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/on-someone%27s-hands)</sub>

This phrasing is often used in the conditional sense to indicate that **if** things go a certain way, **then** the path will be difficult. It's like saying “these difficulties will become your responsibility (or [fall to you](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/fall-to-sb)).”

In this specific instance, the message is essentially:

> I think the Crimean government may [be faced with] a big fight [if it tries to] persuad[e] citizens to endorse joining Russia.